# Is a ScanQuery in Apache Ignite over a single partition single or multi-threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, ignite

I am using a filter within a ScanQuery that does some more logic than simple filtering - it is stateful and creates some aggregates/counters.
Do I need to use thread-safe structures within that filter or is a single partition scanned by a single thread?

Comment: You'll probably have to look at the code for the implementation of IgniteCache.query() that you are using for the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Filter's code will be always executed by a single Thread if you start a single scan query and there are no more scan queries that iterate over the same partition in parallel.

However basing on the `ScanQuery.pageSize` parameter this Thread may vary.

Also make sure that you don't perform any cache related operations in your filter's logic because it may lead to distributed deadlocks.